# In Julia what's the difference between dispatching on abstract types versus parametric subset of abstract types?

Tags: function, performance, julia, dispatch

Are there functional or performance differences between

- `myfunction(x::Real)`, and
- `myfunction(x::T) where {T<:Real}`?

In this case, `Real` is an abstract type which obviously has concrete subtypes like `Float64` and `Int`.

Are there reasons to prefer one versus the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest difference is that you can refer to `T` in the function definition. The other difference is that for `Function`s and `Vararg`s (but no other types, `myfunction(x::T) where {T}` forces specialization.

Other than that, they are exactly the same.